What's causing the memory to blow up?
I just pull a docker image, and it is just a small file. And /dev/nvme0n1p5 uses about 100GB. So What's the problem? How to solve it? Thanks

And what was the usage before you pulled the image? The title mentions memory, which usually means RAM, but then you talk about NVME disks. Which is it?

This question is similar to: No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

well, first thank you for your help. I found my disk actually has space, just nvme0n1p5 shows this problem. So I tried to find the problem. Finally I found /etc/docker/daemon.json file has a ridiculous config. I wrongly set the data_root, so I modified the data_root to /var/lib/docker to solved my problem. Now the disk succeed to have adequate space.

I found my disk actually has space, just nvme0n1p5 shows this problem. So I tried to find the problem. Finally I found /etc/docker/daemon.json file has a ridiculous config. I wrongly set the data_root, so I modified the data_root to /var/lib/docker to solved my problem. Now the disk succeed to have adequate space.
success
